# Git: Comparing changes with remote main not working?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git, I'm sure it must be simple but I'm trying to show the difference between my local main branch and the remote one:

```
git diff main origin/main
```

But it doesn't return anything, yet I can get on Github and see differences in the files. I tried comparing different branches and it's working, what could be the reason to why it doesn't show the differences?

Is it because the comparison is with the local copy of the remote repo and I must fetch it first?

Comment: How can GitHub compare their `main` branch with your local one? You must be comparing something different on GitHub.

Comment: Your last paragraph: yes.

Answer (score 2):

Git does not connect to the remote repo for operations like a diff or a log. It uses what you have stored locally. To update your local references with the changes on the remote, fetch first.

```
git fetch
git diff main origin/main
```

Then you should see the differences you're expecting.

Careful: don't use `git pull` here! After fetching, a pull also merge the remote changes into your local branch. If you just want to *see* the differences, `git fetch` is what you need to do. Then you can use `git diff` or `git log` to examine what got fetched, and then `git merge` to merge the remote changes in if that's what you want to do (or `git pull`, which would fetch again and then merge).